# Intelligent Memory(IM) vs Processing In Memory(PIM)

Tags: memory

I am trying to learn about intelligent memory. I am reading many publications, but still not sure if I understand the concept correctly. I came across PIM and it seems both are the same thing? Can anyone explain if those two things are different or same thing? Any point of direction to read more about IM would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankThomas Intelligent RAM was proposed by David Patterson et al. ("A case for intelligent RAM: IRAM" ([PDF](http://iram.cs.berkeley.edu/papers/IRAM.micro.pdf)), 1997) and uses a full-featured, SIMD-supporting processor. As I understand it, IRAM is a particular kind of PIM. Some PIM ideas focus on specific operations; I would include 3DRAM — a graphics RAM that supported simple ALU ops with memory writes — as a limited form of PIM. With recent stacked DRAM such as Hybrid Memory Cube, Processor *Near* Memory may  be an interesting alternative (avoid logic vs. DRAM process issues).

Comment: The University of California Berkeley [IRAM page](http://iram.cs.berkeley.edu/) might be a good source of information.